# Print Google Map from jQuery Colorbox window

Tags: jquery, google-maps, colorbox

I'm loading a Google Map in a jQuery Colorbox window.  All of that works fine, however I need to find a method to print the map once it's loaded.  I've tried the code below, however it does not grab the entire view-able map, only a portion and the quality is rather low.

First I append a new button to the colorbox, which has a onclick="printColorbox()"
Then the following function fires...

```
function printColorbox()
{
    try 
    {
        if(!$('#ifrmPrint').length) $('body').append('<iframe id="ifrmPrint" src="#" style="width:0pt; height:0pt; border: none;"></iframe>');      
        var print_frame = document.getElementById('ifrmPrint');
        var print_head = $("#cboxContent iframe").contents().find("head").html();
        var print_body = $("#cboxContent iframe").contents().find("body").html()
        var print_doc = (print_frame.contentWindow || print_frame.contentDocument);
        if (print_doc.document) print_doc = print_doc.document;
        // Write printable content
        print_doc.write("<html><head>");
        print_doc.write(print_head);
        print_doc.write('</head><body onload="this.focus(); this.print();">');
        print_doc.write(print_body);
        print_doc.write("</body></html>");
        print_doc.close();
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        self.print();
    }   
}
```

Could anyone shed some light on how I can print the Google map from the colorbox window?  Or if that is not possible, could I save the map as a pdf?

Thank you in advance for any help!!!

Comment: What is what you want to achieve? Insert a map with a fixed location, an image perhaps? Or dynamically insert a google map?

Comment: I want to be able to print the viewable area of the colorbox window which holds my google map.  The colorbox loads up, Google maps loads and my markers get added perfectly, I just need a way to click a print button and print the map.  I'm using the iframe colorbox option too fyi.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22536021/iframe-google-maps-wont-print-in-chrome?s=1|1.9437